# Stouffer-Liptak method for combining P values

Tags: r

I am in the position of needing to combine P.values using the Stouffer-Liptak method for a meta-analysis. My data consists of a dataframe where the rows are genes and the columns contain P.values. Simulated illustration below.

```
Gene  Study 1  Study 2  Study 3
a     0.03     0.001    0.3
b     0.2      0.1      0.02
c     0.04     0.05     0.03
```

There are 25000 genes in total and I need to a snippet of code that will generate combined P.values for all 25,000 genes, one per row, using the Stouffer-Liptak method. Any pointers on how to apply this method using R and Bioconductor will be appreciated.

Cheers,
Ankur.

Comment: type `?apply` in R or search `[r] apply` in the top right search box or are you asking how to actually do the Stouffer-Liptak method?

Comment: I am actually asking how to do the method.

Comment: That looks very good, thank you.

Comment: This looks more like a statistics question, and thus more suitable for stats.statexchange.

Comment: Try `library("sos"); findFn("Liptak")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MetaDE.rawdata` function in `MetaDE` has Stouffer.